# Cannot display an overview of this response error in nexmo

Tags: vonage

i tried to run the code present in the below link
https://github.com/linroex/Nexmo-PHP-Library/blob/master/NexmoMessage.php
but i am getting cannot display overview of this response.warning Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in NexmoMessage.php on line 228.
or else please suggest some api to be used to send sms to phone using php which could be implemented easily

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://docs.nexmo.com/tools/libraries for a list of libraries Nexmo recommends. Personally I'm a fan of https://github.com/fillup/nexmo since I wrote it, but I'm sure https://github.com/appleboy/CodeIgniter-Nexmo-Message is great too. If you try the fillup/nexmo library and have any issues let me know, will be glad to help.

Comment: I added example code into index.php. and i tried to run the code but i got these errors. Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\nexmo-develop/../../config-local.dist.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory inindex.php on line 12 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\nexmo-develop/../../config-local.dist.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in index.php on line 12 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Nexmo\Sms' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\nexmo-develop\index.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\nexmo-develop\index.php on line 17

Comment: i am not clear with how update json file after adding "fillup/nexmo": "dev-master". plzz help me in how to install using composer.json

Comment: Hi @MounicaYelchuri, if you are not familiar with using composer for managing packages and dependencies I highly recommend you check out https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md to learn more about it, it is fantastic.

Comment: As for your error about the missing config file, I think you copied my example code and tried to run it without putting the config file in place. At the root of the repo I have a sample config-local.dist.php file, if you rename i to config-local.php and then go to the src/examples/ folder you should be able to run the sms example by running ```php sms.php```, but the example depends on finding config-local.php two folders higher. You don't have to use the examples though, you can use the library directly and pass your config in an array to the constructor and call the methods directly.

Comment: thank you @Phillip Shipley,It was very useful.worked for me

Comment: i have implemented it, can we pass array of phone numbers to this?

Comment: No, you'd have to loop through your phone numbers and foreach send the message.

Comment: where should i keep this for loop??.. i tried many ways but i was not able to get it..

Comment: @MounicaYelchuri if I understand your use case, you have a list of phone numbers that you want to send a message to. So you need to loop through your array and foreach entry make a call to the Sms library to send the message. So something like https://gist.github.com/fillup/bb319433de8aef3d635e881be89fe164